# How can i align items to center in Tailwind?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am making a progress bar but i am unable to align it to center using tailwind css. It automatically squishes down.
here is the code-

```
                <div className='w-full px-3 py-4'>
                <p>Edit and set up your demo website</p>

                <div className='flex '>
                        <div className='flex-1 grid a-items-center'>

                            <div className='h-1.5 bg-pBar mt-3 rounded-full flex items-center'>
                               <span className='h-1.5 block bg-pink1 rounded-full w-full'></span>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <p className='flex-1'>1 of 4</p>
                </div>
                    
                    
                </div>
```

i tried to add display flex and even grid but the same thing happened.

Comment: add `justify-center`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I really understood your request.

But is [this](https://play.tailwindcss.com/S32K65EF4s) what you are looking for?

Edit: Why you can't align text properly next to a block element.

You can't really align text next to a block element with current css because depending on the letter you use it will "look" not centered. this is due to the way the font is laid out, firefox support cap units which you can use to match it to the capital size of the the letter. But flex alignment will always center relative to the container.

[Here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/KFQCK2KYD2) is what I mean.

Comment: actually i want <p className='flex-1'>1 of 4</p> to perfectly align center with the progress bar

Comment: <p className='flex-1'>1 of 4</p> this is a bit up right thats why

Comment: just remove "items-center" or change it to "items-baseline" I will update the sample

Comment: Just remove *mt-3* keeping other property as it is.

Comment: Text will always "look" not centered next to a block element depending of the letter you are using. This is a common issue for example while aligning text next to an icon. Take a look at the updated sample.