# Tailwind CSS can't align icon and text to center on button

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am trying to align an icon and text to the center of a button but no matter what I seem to do, it does not correctly align.

```
.metamask-icon {
    width:25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-size: contain!important;
    background: url('../../styles/img/metamask-icon.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
```

```
<div className="bg-marine-blue-800 border-marine-blue-500 border-2 text-white text-center py-12 lg:py-20 px-12 md:px-16 lg:px-24 rounded-3xl">
              <h1 className="capitalize font-black  leading-tight my-4">
                Connect your wallet
              </h1>

              <button
                className="flex items-center font-bold uppercase bg-white w-full rounded-full mx-auto py-4 pl-8 block mt-12 mb-6"
                onClick={handleSignInWithMetamask}
              >
                <span className={`account-icon metamask-icon mr-2`}/>
                <span className="text-connect">Metamask</span>
              </button>
                <span className="font-black  leading-tight my-4">or</span>
              <input
                className="accountInput text-connect w-full mt-6"
                type="text"
                placeholder="E-mail"
                value={username}
                onChange={(e) => handleEmailChange(e.target.value)}
              />
              <input
                className="accountInput text-connect w-full mt-6"
                type="password"
                placeholder="Password"
                value={password}
                onChange={(e) => handlePasswordChange(e.target.value)}
              />
              <span className="text-red-500">{error}</span>
              <div className="flex flex-row items-center">
                <button
                  className="font-bold uppercase bg-secondary border border-neutral-50 w-full rounded-full mx-auto py-4 block mt-6 mr-3"
                  onClick={handleClose}
                >
                    CLOSE
                </button>
                <button
                  className="font-bold uppercase bg-primary w-full rounded-full mx-auto py-4 block mt-6 ml-3"
                  onClick={handleEmailSignIn}
                >
                    sign in
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Here is a picture to explain
[Metamask icon and text off center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhlmE.png)

I tried various things like adding `flex-col`, `align-items center` but I can't seem to make it move to the center.

Comment: take a look on this answer I gave in a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75517540/how-can-i-align-items-to-center-in-tailwind

I tried putting your code into a play tailwind. but it gives nothing. easiest way to help you is to have a reproduced scenario that people can debug. But bottom line is flex alignment only align elements relative to the container, align of text might look weird because of the way fonts work. you need to manually adjust the text position as in the sample I put in that answer.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at your answer. This is my first question so not quite sure what is needed for the code snippet for others to best give advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icon and text are already aligned vertically with `items-center`, so I assume you mean you also want to align them horizontally.

To do that using plain CSS in a flex container, you need `justify-content: center`. In Tailwind, you can apply this property with class `justify-center`:

```
<button
  className="flex items-center justify-center font-bold uppercase bg-white w-full rounded-full mx-auto py-4 pl-8 mt-12 mb-6"
  onClick={handleSignInWithMetamask}
>
  <span className={`account-icon metamask-icon mr-2`}/>
  <span className="text-connect">Metamask</span>
</button>
```

(I also removed the class `block` you have in the button, as that applies the same property as `flex`.)

Comment: Yes! this is it, thank you so much. I didn't know items-center only applies to the vertical. Good to know, I am learning. Thank you again.

Comment: Technically, `items-center` applies to the cross axis, while `justify-center` applies to the main axis, and by default in a flex container that's vertical and horizontal respectively. But if you use `flex-col`, for instance, the cross axis will be horizontal and the main axis will be vertical, so the properties will be applied differently than you might think at first.

Comment: Okay this is very good to know and keep in mind. Thank you again.